# Can I Share a Git Repository on a USB Thumbdrive between Windows and OS X?

Tags: windows, macos, git, repository, msysgit

I have a personal git repository on my USB thumbdrive that I maintain with msysGit (http://msysgit.github.com/, version 1.8.0), which is installed as a portable app on said thumbdrive.

This setup works quite well when I'm using it with Windows 7 at work.  Unfortunately, when I try to work with the same repository using git (version 1.8.1) on Mac OS X Snow Leopard (10.6.8) at home, I get the following error from the Terminal:

```
$ git diff
fatal: Could not chdir to 'e:/': No such file or directory
```

`'e:/'` is clearly referring to the Windows-based address of the directory containing this repo.

Can these git installations be configured to work together?  I'm still learning git and would rather not employ a solution that involves making copies as I'm already doing that to back up this thumbdrive's entire contents to my Mac's hard drive and Dropbox using `rsync`.

**Update:** Here's what I'd typically to do add files to my repo.  Am I doing anything wrong?

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Username\Documents>E:

E:\>PortableApps\Git\git-bash.bat

Username@Username /e (master)
$ git add launch.bat
```